# PgAdmin3 не подключается к удаленной базе

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, psql, pgadmin

Не могу подключиться к удаленной базе через pgAdmin3, хотя удаленное подключение разрешено и через psql с того же компьютера все подключается нормально. Подскажите в какую сторону копать.

Comment: Может проблема в самом pgAdmin3? Я столкнулся с кучей проблем с ним (под linux), в итоге поставил версию pgAdmin4 и больше их не испытываю.

Comment: @pgAdmin, не знаю, может  быть конечно. Но 4 версия какая-то очень уж странная по части интерфейса.